# “Act one” and “Scene one” in dramatist instead of “Act I” and “Scene I”

Tags: numbering, dramatist

With dramatist package to type theater play, how to get first act and first scene show a full-letter number ? And how to make it work only for first acts and scenes, the other acts and scene should remain roman numbers.

As example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}


\begin{document}
\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Should render:

```
Act one
Lorem ipsum

Scene one
Lorem ipsum

Scene II
Lorem ipsum

Act II
Lorem ipsum

Scene one
Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Not everybody is acquainted with `dramatist`. Can you please add a small example to play with?

Comment: Certainly @egreg, I just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the representation of the counters `act` and `scene`. I also change `\printscenenum` in order it just prints the scene number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\renewcommand{\theact}{%
  \ifnum\value{act}=1 one\else\roman{act}\fi
}
\renewcommand{\thescene}{%
  \ifnum\value{scene}=1 one\else\roman{scene}\fi
}
\renewcommand{\printscenenum}{\scenenumfont\thescene}




\begin{document}

\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, but I still asking for any improvement before making this tread as resolved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{ifthen} % To test if a scene is the first one

\newcounter{allwaysone}
\stepcounter{allwaysone} % This counter is just here to make the test in the \makeactfullleteriffirst command

\newcommand\makeactfullletteriffirst[1]{%
  % Command for testing if the act is the first one then return “one”. If not return the input value.
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\actnumfont \roman{allwaysone}}}%
  {%
    one%
  }%
  {%
    #1%
  }%
}%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\m@ke@cthead[1]{%
  \actheadstart
  {\parindent \z@
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
  \printactname \printsep \makeactfullletteriffirst{\printactnum} % here is the relevant line
  \fi
  \printacttitle{#1}
  \afteract}
  }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\act

Lorem ipsum

\scene

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```